# How can you run a proxmox server on a ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, server, proxmox

I would like to run a proxmox server on a Ubuntu EC2 Instance.

I know this may sound crazy but I do not have any spare hardware to run a promox server on. Would it be possible to run this on a Ubuntu EC2 Instance?

If i was to download proxmox on a flash drive, can i insert it into my computer and install it (overiding) the ubuntu instance and just using the hardware? Is this possible AWS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can install pretty much anything on an EC2 instance most of the time. Your question is too generic, not focused on anything specific. Please do your own research and come back with a specific question about your failed attempts.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. So what I am trying to attempt is to install promox (a virtualisation software) to then further use the hardware AWS is offering via the EC2 to run VM's on proxmox. I would have to install proxmox on a USB flash drive then boot strap the ISO via that flash drive.

Comment: What does the USB drive have to do with this? You can't plug a USB drive into an EC2 instance.

Comment: I don't think this is doable - read: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/use-on-amazon-ec2.5475/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read this but really thought there was another way. I shall do some more digging to see if its possible.

Comment: Unless you plan to run on a metal instance, you're going to be running a virtualization system inside a virtualization system, which is generally not going to end well.  You'd really be better off using EC2 to manage your instance directly, rather than fighting it.

Comment: Can you refer to the below, this may help, as they have a way to install promox on ubuntu. 
https://raspberrytips.com/install-proxmox-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run Proxmox on EC2, but if you want to host VM guests you need to run on an instance type that supports nested virtualisation, which is only the "metal" instances. These start at about $4/hour.

Running containers works fine on any standard x64 instance type, though.

I posted a guide to installing Proxmox on EC2 here:

https://github.com/thenickdude/proxmox-on-ec2

The tricky parts that the guide fixes up automatically are harmonising the network configuration generated by Debian's cloud-init package with Proxmox's nonstandard ifupdown2 package.